# Substitute Wingding fonts for linux

Tags: aspose

I am using Java aspose.words and trying to build a pdf from docx/ppt in linux. The docx-document has an list with bulletpoints. These bulletpoints use the symbol font.

When i create the pdf with aspose these bulletpoints are shown in webdings font as a clapperboard.
I did not find any free font (for commercial use) that is an equivalent to the symbol font. Does anyone know a good solution to show correct bulletpoints in list?

I found the way to substitute fonts, but i don't know which font to use:

```
TableSubstitutionRule tableSubstitutionRule = fontSettings.getSubstitutionSettings().getTableSubstitution();
tableSubstitutionRule.addSubstitutes("Symbol", "?WHICH_FONT?");
```

Comment: Do we need to set above mentioned symbol font (ZapfDingbat) before conversion? If yes, how can we set?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a known peculiarity. Windows “Symbol” font is a symbolic font (like “Webdings”, “Wingdings”, etc.) which uses Unicode PUA. Thus substitution of this font will cause different glyphs rendering. Provided Mac/Linux “Symbol” font on the other hand is a proper Unicode font (for example Greek characters are in the U+0370…U+03FF Greek and Coptic block). So these fonts are incompatible and Mac/Linux “Symbol” font cannot be used instead of Windows “Symbol” without additional actions. In this particular case you have to change the bullet codepoint from PUA U+F0B7 (or U+00B7 which also can be used in MS Word for symbolic fonts) to the U+2022 in the document to use the Mac “Symbol” font. See the following code for example:

```java
Document doc = new Document("/Users/mac1/Downloads/in.docx");

for (com.aspose.words.List lst : doc.getLists())
{
    for (com.aspose.words.ListLevel level : lst.getListLevels())
    {
        if (level.getFont().getName().equals("Symbol") && level.getNumberFormat().equals("\uF0B7"))
        {
            level.setNumberFormat("\u2022");
        }
    }
}

doc.save("/Users/mac1/Downloads/out.pdf");
```

If this does not help, please post your question in [Aspose.Words support forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8) and attach your input and output document there.